# See which files with a specific file extension changed (Git)

Tags: git

I want to see which files with a specific file extension changed

something like:

`git show 8a656c2 --file-extention java`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done with a simple glob:

```
git show -- '*.java'
```